# How can I use variables in Python fstring while including backslashes that dont escape the next character

Tags: python, string, f-string, rawstring

I am trying to write the following string

> Target\=R80.40

exactly as it is shown above, while R80.40 should be a value derived from a variable.

So the solution should be something like

```
version='R80.40'
print(f'Target\\={version}')
OUTPUT: Target\=R80.40
```

But I want my string in the code to look nicer without the double backslash.

So in this case the solution can be to use a raw string r''

```
version='R80.40'
print(r'Target\=' +version)
OUTPUT: Target\=R80.40
```

**Is it possible to use both fstring and raw string?**

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is simple as using both fstring a raw-string at once.

```
version='R80.40'
print(fr'Target\={version}')
OUTPUT: Target\=R80.40
```

The string is preceded by both f and r.